# Can someone explain how to design a Regex that works regardless whether there is a space or not after/before HTML tags

Tags: regex

Need to use Regex instead of parser to lift attributes from HMTL/XML page, but can't make the Regex `<span class='street-address'> (?<Street>.*)` lift `2346 21st Ave NE` from the following text (spaced exactly like that), in Rubular.

```
<span class='street-address'>
2346 21st Ave NE
</span>
```

Also the Regex I have only works if I condense the text and there are spaces after the first HTML tag and before the last HTML tag. If I change the Regex to eliminate those spaces, then spaced HTML tags are skipped. I want to make the Regex as dynamic as possible.

How can I construct a Regex that works regardless whether there is a space or not after/before HTML tags or line breaks?

Comment: You shouldn't change your question after an answer is already answered to your question, since it generates confusions and deprecated answers. You should create a new question according to your newer needs.

Comment: I see, I'll create a new question. Thank you @Fede.

Comment: no problem, I'll help too :)

Comment: @Fede, you're a freakin champion. I'll delete this comment later since it's a non-question/non-info comment, but is there anyway I can add to your rep? I'm new to StackOverflow and coding, so I'm as dumb as a brick.

Comment: lol, I'm glad to help. What do you mean by add to my rep?

Comment: Hm, in other forums I can either comment, upvote your profile, or give you points. Is the best way to select best answer in StackOverflow?

Comment: you can offer bounties or upvote answers if you feel you consider it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can find in almost all the answers related to xhtml and regex, you **should not use regex to parse html** unless you really know what html content is involved. I would use a html parser instead.

You have just to use the `s` (single line flag) and also use a lazy quantifier

```
<span class='street-address'>(?<Street>.*?)<\/span>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP3fA9/1)**

You can also use the inline `s` flag like this:

```
(?s)<span class='street-address'>(?<Street>.*?)<\/span>
 ^--- here
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to use regex flags, you could use a well know trick by using two opposite sets like `[\s\S]` like this:

```
<span class='street-address'>(?<Street>[\s\S]*?)<\/span>
```

Just for you to know, this trick means:

```
\s     --> matches whitespace (spaces, tabs). 
\S     --> matches non whitespace (same as: [^\s])
[\s\S] --> matches whitespace or non whitespace (so... everything)
```

You can use this trick with whatever set you want, like:

```
[\s\S] whitespace or non whitespace
[\w\W] word or non word
[\d\D] digit or non digit
[\b\B] word boundary or non word boundary
```

Comment: I see, but why are the backslashes before `s` not needed? The new regex is not solving the issue of line breaks in Rubular though. According to http://qntm.org/files/re/re.html, line breaks can be address `<span class='street-address'>(^?<Street>.*?$)<\/span>`, with `^` and `$`, but it's not returning any matches.

Comment: @exlo The anchors your meant `^` and `$` are used to match start and end of line repectively. They are commonly used with `m` (multiline flag). Btw, didn't understand `why are the backslashes before s not needed`...

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how does including an opposite set of non-whitespace and whitespace characters work? (Ah, I misunderstood the s line flag, so I was asking about the backslashes, the backslashes were in the context of the set you mentioned afterward since I'd come across it in my research). Also, I couldn't find the single-line flag in your first example.

Comment: @exlo The `s` flag is in the second text box. About the trick, I updated the answer with the explanation. Keep in mind that `\s` and `\S` are in a character class `[\s\S]` so that's how you can use the trick. Think a character class as a set, for instance `[123]` will match 1, 2 or 3... so if you have `[\s\S]` it will match whitespace or non whitespace... same happens for `[\w\W]` (word or non word) or for `[\d\D]` (digit or non digit)

Comment: @Fede is giving you excellent advice - use a parser.  Must read on this topic (and for life in general):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/505191